# Why doesn't the inner loop increment each time?

Tags: python

I am a new person to programming and still wrapping my head around the logic. The code I am laying out for you works: it produces the first N prime numbers. i.e. if user enters 10, the code will produce all primes up to and including 10. This was an assignment question, by the way. This is how my professor laid it out.

Also, if I am not displaying my code correctly, please give me some helpful hints about how to do that. I don't know what a fence is, but I indented each line 4 spaces, if that helps.

I stepped through this code in debug mode, and noticed that the value of j never went beyond 2 or 3. Why not?

```
n = int(input("Please enter the number up to which you want to find prime 
numbers: "))
count = 0  

if n > 1:
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        isPrime = True  # set flag to True
        for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                isPrime = False
                break

        if isPrime:
            print(i, "is a prime number.")
            count += 1
else:
    print("Prime numbers must be greater than 1.")

print(count, "prime numbers have been found.")
```

There were no error messages that I could detect.

Comment: What is the value of `i` for the code you ran in the debugger? `j` will never go higher than `i // 2`.

Comment: Try with *n* = 11, and you'll see that *j* becomes greater. The bigger *n*, the bigger *j*  can become.

Comment: When you run this algorithm, the maximum value `j` will reach is `p // 2` where `p` is the largest prime number `<= n`.

Comment: I tried your code inputting 100. The maximum `j` I got was 48.

Comment: Thanks guys, that is obviously what I did incorrectly. I only tried up to 10 per my instructor. Use a little more imagination, and I could have resolved this. lol I need a rubber duck.